# moderncv, list of publications newest first

Tags: moderncv, sorting

How to organize the list of publication showing the newest first?  Other users have suggested to use `plainyr.bst`, because this `bst` file already organizes by year,  then change the single line from `ITERATE {call.type$}` to `REVERSE {call.type$}`, and save with a different name.  I am not sure why but this simple procedure is not working for me, I get no output at all.  However when compiling with `plainyr.bst` I do get the expected output with oldest publication first.  Could anyone provide further help?  I use MikTex2.9 Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave us no minimal working example here just a guess and the way I do it for my own cv:

I have one special bib file, containing my works for the cv.  **I sort them by my own, so the first bib entry in the file is the newest one.**

Then most of work is done.  Now you can use style `unsrtdin` to get the wished result.  I have used package `filecontents` to add a bib file.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{book1,
  author    = {John Doe and John Smith},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  edition   = {edition},
  year      = {2014},
}
@BOOK{book2,
  author    = {John Doe and Eva Smith},
  title     = {Title2},
  publisher = {Publisher2},
  edition   = {edition},
  year      = {2013},
}
@MISC{misc1,
  author = {Jim Knopf},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {2012},
}
@MISC{misc2,
  author = {John Doe and Max Musterfrau},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                  
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                          
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                           
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                         
\email{john@doe.org}                           
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                     
\extrainfo{additional information}    
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a} % change image name 
\quote{Some quote}                    

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman} % German cv

\makecvtitle

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
\renewcommand{\refname}{Veröffentlichungen}  % instead "Publications"
\nocite{*}                   % cite all entrys in bib file
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin} % german bib styles: gerplain, plaindin, unsrtdin
                             % compare with plain (wrong "and" instead German "und")
                             % gerplain: -> 12 errors \sc undefined, missing "`und"' or "`;"'
                             % plaindin, unsrtdin: unwanted bibitems
\bibliography{\jobname}      % bib file \jobname.bib

\end{document}
```