# Publication section in moderncv

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

I am writing CV using 'moderncv'. The problem is I did not find any suitable template for section of **publications** . Any hint would be appreciated.

PS:I use .tex file and did not create any .bib file. I use command pdflatex and biblatex seem not working under this circumstances. I am looking for a simple template for publications which I can implement it in my current .tex file.

Comment: see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123805/creating-bibliographies-with-biblatex-and-moderncv

Comment: I have re-tagged your question since you seem to be not so keen on using `biblatex`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79496/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201827/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85965/35864.